# Why webpack includes elliptic bn.js modules in my bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack

webpack-bundle-analyzer shows elliptic and bn.js included in my vendor.js
But these modules are not used in code or included in package.json.

npm ls bn.js gives:

```
├─┬ eslint-import-resolver-webpack@0.8.1
│ └─┬ node-libs-browser@1.1.1
│   └─┬ crypto-browserify@3.11.0
│     └─┬ browserify-sign@4.0.0
│       └── bn.js@4.11.6
```

Comment: This was happening because of including randomstring module which uses crypto module. If crypto module is used in front end code then all crypto function get included in front end js bundle.

Comment: Could you tell me how to deal with this problem? Because this is causing my overall bundle size to be larger then webpack 1 (in which elliptic and bn.js were not included).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to say, for example, "yarn why crypto" and see what package depends on crypto because this is using the webpack behavior of auto-polyfilling a nodejs module

Answer (score 8):

Webpack includes `elliptic` and `bn.js` (and other, smaller modules) in your bundle if you import `crypto` as a dependency somewhere in your code.

To avoid these *huge* dependencies, you can look for a specific npm module which provides *just the function(ality) you need*.

For example, I was importing `crypto` to do;

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', buf);
```

... instead (in this situation...), you can install the [`create-hmac` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-hmac), and do;

```
const createHmac = require('create-hmac');
const hmac = createHmac('sha1', buf);
```

In case you need some motivation; removing `crypto` as a dependancy trimmed 150Kb off our gzipped bundle size (but YMMV depending on which crypto methods you're using).

Comment: In my case, I was using `jsonwebtoken` in my codebase and it imported the same dependencies. I can confirm the saving is significant :)

Comment: Even a tiny dep like `crypto-random-string` brings in a ton of leaf deps via `crypto` :(

Comment: If your bundle bloated  due to  `jsonwebtoken` as mentioned by Mickael. You may try `jwt-decode` if you are using it to decode your jwt token.

Comment: You could also stick with `jsonwebtoken` and give [dynamic imports](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) a try. Working like a charm for me in Next.js

Answer (score -1):

Those are dependencies of your dependencies. For example [source](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/browserify-sign/blob/master/package.json#L25)