# Common.js, Vendor.js and App.js too big on Build (Nuxt)

Tags: vue.js, web, webpack, nuxt.js, web-performance

I am working on an existing project and I noticed the JavaScript files fetched from the server are way too big.

I am having 50MB Resources fetched on some pages and this page just consist of text and one image and I am still getting a resources of 9MB.

I have tried lazy-loading images and disabled prefetched links in my nuxt.config.js [Here is the network tab for one of the pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKIg4.png)

Here is the
[Webpack Build Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecTMV.png)

[Webpack Bundle Analyzer Link](https://bundle.tiiny.site/)

Here is the Package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.8.4",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.6.0",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@nuxtjs/toast": "^3.2.1",
    "blueimp-md5": "^2.12.0",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "coffee-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "coffeescript": "^2.4.1",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.0.17",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.12.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "imagemin-gifsicle": "^6.0.1",
    "isotope-layout": "^3.0.6",
    "jimp": "^0.9.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.6",
    "lazysizes": "^5.2.0",
    "lqip-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "module": "^1.2.5",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.14.7",
    "nuxt-lazy-load": "^1.0.5",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.4.456",
    "psd": "^3.2.0",
    "responsive-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "sqip-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-facebook-login-component": "^1.3.7",
    "vue-google-auth": "^1.0.5",
    "vue-google-signin-button-directive": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-ionicons": "^3.0.4",
    "vue-lazyload": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.20",
    "vue-paystack": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-session": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-slick": "^1.1.15",
    "vue-toasted": "^1.1.27",
    "vueisotope": "^3.1.2",
    "webp-loader": "^0.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@bazzite/nuxt-optimized-images": "^0.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/svg": "^0.1.12",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^8.0.0",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^8.0.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^7.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1"
  }
```

Comment: Is this after executing `npm run dev` ?

Comment: Yes, it is after npm run dev and even on production, I am getting the same result

Comment: Well I dont think it is imposible but sound very unlikely that production build is same as development one. Production builds are always optimized (unless yur nuxt/webpack is badly misconfigured). I don't think anyone can help you with so little info. Post your `package.json`, `nuxt.config.js`. Try to run [bundle analyzer](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#analyze)

Comment: I have updated it @MichalLevý

Comment: Analyzer output is not that much useful as an image...

Comment: https://bundle.tiiny.site/ here is the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42492410/why-webpack-includes-elliptic-bn-js-modules-in-my-bundle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65118808/the-same-dependency-is-included-many-times-in-my-bundle

Comment: Check all the dependencies - especially one included multiple times in the bundle. You are probably using one of the libraries in a wrong way (importing everything). Google "how to treeshake lodash"